# Why is my req.body empty? MEAN Stack - NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

The path my data takes from front-end to back-end works great until I try to send a post request and access req.body.

The form data is being sent correctly as I can see it as it should be in the network tab of the developer tools, but when I try to access it, the req.body object is empty. Please help!! I'm sure it's something small, but I'm losing sleep over here.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
  );
  next();
});

app.use('/api/manifests', manifestsRoutes);
```

```
router.post("", (req, res, next) => {
  const manifest = new Manifest({
    hazardId: req.body.hazardId,
    serviceDate: req.body.serviceDate,
    service: req.body.service,
    gallonsRemoved: req.body.gallonsRemoved,
    servicer: {
      name: req.body.servicerName,
      company: req.body.servicerCompany,
      email: req.body.servicerEmail,
      phone: req.body.servicerPhone
    },
    serviceFrequency: req.body.serviceFrequency,
    disposalFacility: req.body.disposalFacility,
    repairsMade: req.body.repairsMade
  });
  manifest.save().then(createdManifest => {
    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Manifest created!',
      manifest: {
        ...createdManifest,
        id: createdManifest._id
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: manifest,
      error: error
    });
  });
});
```

```
addManifest(
    hazardId: string,
    serviceDate: Date,
    service: string,
    gallonsRemoved: string,
    servicer: {
        name: string,
        company: string,
        email: string,
        phone: string
    },
    serviceFrequency: string,
    disposalFacility: string,
    repairsMade: string
    ) {
      const datestr = (new Date(serviceDate)).toDateString();
      const manifestData = new FormData();
      manifestData.append('hazardId', hazardId);
      manifestData.append('serviceDate', datestr);
      manifestData.append('service', service);
      manifestData.append('gallonsRemoved', gallonsRemoved);
      manifestData.append('servicerName', servicer.name);
      manifestData.append('servicerCompany', servicer.company);
      manifestData.append('servicerEmail', servicer.email);
      manifestData.append('servicerPhone', servicer.phone);
      manifestData.append('serviceFrequency', serviceFrequency);
      manifestData.append('disposalFacility', disposalFacility);
      manifestData.append('repairsMade', repairsMade);
      this.http
        .post<{ message: string; manifest: Manifest }>(
          'http://localhost:3000/api/manifests',
          manifestData
        )
        .subscribe(responseData => {
          console.log(responseData);
        });
  }
```

POST data in network tab of debugger:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/manifests
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2974
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 08 Feb 2020 06:29:58 GMT
ETag: W/"b9e-YODjimn7ORF5Sf5mzZD4Nwk6VPg"
X-Powered-By: Express
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1282
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryhOXfO3S3AyABWgsS
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/enter-manifest
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
```

Form data:

```
hazardId: 146852
serviceDate: Fri Feb 07 2020
service: Full pump and clean (all solids and liquids removed)
gallonsRemoved: 50
servicerName: test
servicerCompany: test
servicerEmail: test
servicerPhone: test
serviceFrequency: Quarterly
disposalFacility: test
repairsMade: null
```

Comment: Please show us what you see for the POST request and data in the network tab in the Chrome debugger for the outgoing request.  It is possible that what you think it should look like is not what your server is configured for.

Comment: I added all the info that I can see in the network tab

Comment: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` is probably not what you want for your POST.  You don't have a middleware handler for that data type.  I don't know your client environment/APIs, but you have middleware for `application/json` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so with that middleware, you need the client to send one of those.

Comment: Great!! Thank you!
Do you have any idea how I would send as `application/json` vs `multipart/form-data`?

I have no problem researching on my own, but if it's a quick fix, you could save me some time!

Comment: I do not know Angular, but I think Angular is guessing what content-type to send and not guessing what you want. You can perhaps tell it what content-type to send by setting that content-type in your outgoing headers. I'd suggest you use `application/json`, but you can also try `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as either can work with your current server middleware. Hopefully, Angular will see that content-type and take the formData and convert it to that type. You can probably also just send a Javascript object instead as you aren't using any of the unique features of FormData.

Comment: After a little more reading, it looks like you shouldn't be using a FormData object if you don't want `multipart/form-data`.  Instead, use a Javascript object or make your own JSON and set the content-type header to the type of data you have created.

Comment: This was correct. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `addManifest` function to this:

```
addManifest(
    hazardId: string,
    serviceDate: Date,
    service: string,
    gallonsRemoved: string,
    servicer: {
        name: string,
        company: string,
        email: string,
        phone: string
    },
    serviceFrequency: string,
    disposalFacility: string,
    repairsMade: string
    ) {
      const datestr = (new Date(serviceDate)).toDateString();
      var manifestData = {
        'hazardId': hazardId,
        'serviceDate': datestr,
        'gallonsRemoved': gallonsRemoved,
        'servicerName': servicer.name,
        'servicerCompany': servicer.company,
        'servicerEmail': servicer.email,
        'servicerPhone': servicer.phone,
        'serviceFrequency': serviceFrequency,
        'disposalFacility': disposalFacility,
        'repairsMade': repairsMade
      };
      const httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':  'application/json'})};
      this.http
        .post<{ message: string; manifest: Manifest }>(
          'http://localhost:3000/api/manifests',
          manifestData,
          httpOptions
        )
        .subscribe(responseData => {
          console.log(responseData);
        });
  }
```

Changed `FormData` to `JavaScriptObject` and added `JSON Content-Type` for the request header

Will this work?

Comment: This worked. Thank you!! A tutorial I went through always used FormData. I shouldn't have followed blindly. Thank you for your help.